# Combine multiple interfaces into one main interface

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I want to declare multiple interfaces for my WCF Service. These interfaces should go into one main interface by implementing them. This works in Visual Studio, but when I start my WCF Service it crashes, because the multiple interfaces are missing the `ServiceContract` attribute.
I don't want to add this attribute to them, because the client should only use my main interface which has the `ServiceContract` attribute.

Here's one of the small interfaces:

```
public interface IBroadcastHostFunctions
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SubscribeToBroadcasts();

    [OperationContract]
    void UnsubscribeFromBroadcasts();
}
```

This is the main interface as is should look like:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof (IHostFunctionsCallback))]
public interface IHostFunctions : IBroadcastHostFunctions
{
}
```

Does anyone know how to realize this without adding the `ServiceContract` attribute to `IBroadcastHostFunctions`?

Comment: You have decorated the methods on `IBroadcastHostFunctions` with `OperationContract` attributes so that type already requires `System.ServiceModel`. I see absolutely no valid reason why you should not also add `ServiceContract` to that interface.

If your clients or consumers wish to use the narrow interface instead of the conglomerate, let them. It will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: Doesn't this require an endpoint entry for each interface? (in App.config)

Comment: No. You can publish your service as the conglomerate, with one end-point. Consumers can consider it to be whatever they like. They could even type out their own interface which matches a selected part of your contract and use it to create a client proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing a WCF service, you cannot (and should not) control the interface types that consumers use to create client-proxies for it. They are free to define their own interface or generate one with a tool (from the WSDL) and, as long as it conforms to your service's contract, it will work.

The only possible reason to avoid decorating `IBroadcastHostFunctions` with `ServiceContract` would be to avoid a dependency on `System.ServiceModel` but you have decorated the methods on `IBroadcastHostFunctions` with `OperationContract` attributes so that type already requires `System.ServiceModel`.

Go ahead and add `ServiceContract` to `IBroadcastHostFunctions` and let your consumers run free.

Comment: The reason why I am doing this is that I don't want one interface with hundreds of methods. Also if a client doesn't need feature xy we can compile it without implementing this interface. (We have different builds for our clients as they need special features for their production)
Also by simply adding `[ServiceContract]` my service starts.

Comment: Now I've got another problem: Doing the same with callbacks doesn't work. (Without `[ServiceContract]`) SvcUtil.exe generates only a proxy for my HostFunctions and not my callbacks. Do you know what to do?